# Java program to keep track of team score

Tags: java

Edit: I updated the below code from before and am able to get the individual quarter amounts. I'm not sure why my "teamTotal" method is not adding together all four quarters. I figured it was supposed to iterate over all of the team 1 and 2 scores and add them together to get the separate totals. However, when I run it I am only getting zero returned back to me.

```
public class Offical4 {

static int team1[] = new int[4];
static int team2[] = new int[4];
static int teamOneScore = 0;
static int teamTwoScore = 0;
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {


    for (int Quarter = 1; Quarter <= 4; Quarter++) {
        System.out.println("Quarter " + Quarter);
        for (int qtr = 0; qtr < 4; qtr++) {
            quarterScoring(team1, team2, qtr);

        }
        System.out.println("Q"+ (Quarter)  + " score for team 1 is " + teamOneScore);
        System.out.println("Q"+ (Quarter)  + " score for team 2 is " + teamTwoScore);
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    int team1Total = teamTotal(team1);
    int team2Total = teamTotal(team2);

    displayGameResults(team1, team2);

    System.out.println("Team one total is " + team1Total);



}
static int pointsScored;

static int teamTotal(int[] team) {
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i =0; i < team.length; i++)
        sum += team[i];

    return sum;
}

static void quarterScoring(int[] team1, int[] team2, int qtr) {
        System.out.println("What team scored?(1 or 2)");
        int scoreResult = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How many points did they score (1,2, or 3)");
        int pointsScored = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (scoreResult == 1) {
            teamOneScore += pointsScored;
        } else if (scoreResult == 2) {
            teamTwoScore += pointsScored;
        }
        if (scoreResult > 2) {
            System.out.println("Invalid team - quarter has ended.");
        }


}

static void displayGameResults(int[] team1, int[] team2) {
    System.out.println("Team 1 score is " + teamOneScore);
    System.out.println("Team 2 score is " + teamTwoScore);

    if(teamOneScore > teamTwoScore){
        System.out.println("Team one is the winner");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Team two Two wins");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please tell what output should it print by editing the question.

Comment: do you mean total point of each team?

Comment: @Anish B. 
It should print the winning team and the total number of points scored by each team for the four quarters

Comment: @VietDD
Yes, at the each I would to print the total number of points scored by each of the two teams.

Answer (score 0):

Use the two arrays at the top of your code to keep track of the score for each team in each quarter.  Then to get their totals add the values of the array up.  You can use an enhanced for loop for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to keep track total point of each team, one idea as bellow

```
public class Main {

    static int team1[] = new int[4];        // define here
    static int team2[] = new int[4];        // define here

    static int teamOneScore = 0;            // define here
    static int teamTwoScore = 0;            // define here

    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

...
```

Then you can

```
System.out.println("What team scored?(1 or 2)");
int iTeam = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.println("How many points did they score (1,2, or 3)");
int pointsScored = keyboard.nextInt();
        
if (iTeam == 1) {
    teamOneScore += pointsScored;   // Total score of Team 1
}
else if (iTeam == 2) {
    teamTwoScore += pointsScored;   // Total score of Team 2
}
```

And

```
System.out.println("Team 1 score is " + teamOneScore);
System.out.println("Team 2 score is " + teamTwoScore);
```

One more thing, I think you need to validate what input value is before do anything.